# Tableau - Dividing two different measures from a custom query data source

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a custom union query in tableau with the following data:

[Rate Breach Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksl1j.png)

[Volume Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfxvH.png)

I was able to get tableau to display the correct values for Rates Confirm Volume and RateBreaches, however I could not divide the breaches value by the volume value (4/126).

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li5Bq.png)

These are my calculated fields for each measure:

[Rates Confirm Volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB3dc.png)

[Rate Breach %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7UAa.png)

I would like the Rate Breach% to read 3.17% (4/124 * 100).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap these in sums. sum(ratebreaches)/sum(rates confirm volume)

[image]